How can I keep Windows 10 from opening Microsoft Edge (rather than my default browser) when I click on hyperlinks in Windows dialog boxes?
Sometimes Windows dialog boxes contain hyperlinks. Here's an example. If I right-click on a PDF, select Properties, go to the Details tab, and select "Remove Properties and Personal Information", it brings up a dialog box with the hyperlink "What personal information might be in a file?"

The problem is that clicking on that hyperlink doesn't open anything in my default browser (Firefox). Instead, it opens in Microsoft Edge. I don't know why. As far as I can tell, Firefox is recognized as my default browser in every way. I don't use Microsoft Edge for anything.
Does anyone know how to keep Edge from being the browser for this kind of hyperlink?

Edge has a few places where it overrides the setting in windows, and just completely ignores it. If you want to keep using Edge, go into its settings, privacy, and find a setting there that it will open pdf files with edge.

@LPChip I'm not sure what you mean. Edge doesn't try to open my PDFs (and I certainly don't want it to open my PDFs).

@76987, Your question is clear, to me, but others needed clarification, so I took the liberty of adding an image. The link opens a Help file, but only in MS Edge. On this PC, I've disabled Edge and EdgeView2 using Sordum's Edge Blocker (https://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v2-0/), and that link does nothing unless Edge is enabled -- it does not open in Firefox or other browser.

@KJ, As you state, the link is built into Explorer, and likely is quite specific. Would someone from EU please comment if that is the behavior in Win 11 in your locale, where decoupling browser and OS is mandated? Thanks.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks for helping out. For me it doesn't open a Help file. Instead, it goes to a "Windows help and learning" page at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows. I have no problem going to that page on Firefox. So I'm not sure why I couldn't have Windows set up so that clicking on "What personal information might be in a file?" opens that page in Firefox.
